# Peered network to servicenetworking.googleapis.com doesn't have imported routes, when created with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

First of all I have to apologize and admit that I am new GCP so sorry if I am unclear with anything here.

I have two terraform recipes, one where I am setting up google cloud sql, and some networking around it. And one where I am setting up some other resources and networking supporting them. The end goal is to make it so that resources in the second recipe can access the cloud sql instance established in the first.

I have verified that the network resources established in the first recipe, do allow connections to the cloud sql instance. But when I attempt to test the connection from an instance in the second recipe it doesn't work. Upon reviewing things. I noticed the following:

- The peered network connection between the vpc in the second recipe and servicenetworking.googleapis.com doesn't import any routes, but the peered vpc in the first one does.
- The project ids for the two peering connections are different, even if deployed from the same recipe (as an experiment I moved the peering connection from recipe 1 to recipe 2 and they still come out with different project ids for the peered network they are peering too )

The following is the network for recipe 2:

```
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc-network" {
  name = "vpc-network-${var.environment}"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
  routing_mode = "GLOBAL"
  delete_default_routes_on_create = true
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet" {
  name                     = "subnet-${var.environment}"
  ip_cidr_range            = var.subnet_cidr
  region                   = var.gcp_region
  network                  = google_compute_network.vpc-network.name
  private_ip_google_access = true
}

resource "google_compute_route" "egress-internet" {
  name             = "egress-internet-${var.environment}"
  dest_range       = "0.0.0.0/0"
  network          = google_compute_network.vpc-network.name
  next_hop_gateway = "default-internet-gateway"
}

resource "google_compute_router" "router" {
  name    = "router-${var.environment}"
  region  = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.region
  network = google_compute_network.vpc-network.name
}

resource "google_compute_router_nat" "nat-router" {
  name                               = "nat-router-${var.environment}"
  router                             = google_compute_router.router.name
  region                             = google_compute_router.router.region
  nat_ip_allocate_option             = "AUTO_ONLY"
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"

  subnetwork {
    name                    = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.name
    source_ip_ranges_to_nat = ["ALL_IP_RANGES"]
  }
  log_config {
    enable = true
    filter = "ERRORS_ONLY"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "iap-bastion" {
  name    = "iap-bastion-${var.environment}"
  network = google_compute_network.vpc-network.self_link
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }
  target_tags   = ["bastion"]
  source_ranges = ["35.235.240.0/20"] # This range contains all IP addresses that IAP uses for TCP forwarding.
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "private-ip-addr" {
  name          = "private-ip-addr-${var.environment}"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc-network.id
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "service-network-connection" {
  network = google_compute_network.vpc-network.id
  service = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private-ip-addr.name]
}
```

The following is the recipe for the sql and network for recipe 1:

```
resource "random_id" "db_name_suffix" {
  byte_length = 2
}


resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql-db" {
  name             = "sql-db-${var.environment}-${random_id.db_name_suffix.hex}"
  region           = var.gcp_region
  database_version = var.rds_db_version
  deletion_protection = false

  depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private-vpc-connection]
  settings {
    tier = var.rds_instance_type
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = false
      private_network = google_compute_network.sql-db-network.id
    }
  }
}

resource "google_sql_user" "sql-db-user" {
  name = "user"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.sql-db.name
  password = data.vault_generic_secret.postgres_password.data[var.environment]
}




resource "google_compute_network" "sql-db-network" {
  name = "sql-db-network-${var.environment}"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
  routing_mode = "GLOBAL"
  delete_default_routes_on_create = true
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "sql-db-subnet" {
  name                     = "sql-db-subnet-${var.environment}"
  ip_cidr_range            = var.holocron_cidr
  region                   = var.gcp_region
  network                  = google_compute_network.sql-db-network.name
  private_ip_google_access = true
}


resource "google_compute_global_address" "sql-db-private-ip-addr" {
  name          = "sql-db-private-ip-addr-${var.environment}"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = google_compute_network.sql-db-network.id
}
resource "google_compute_network_peering" "sql-db-network-to" {
  name = "sql-db-network-to-${var.environment}"
  network = google_compute_network.sql-db-network.self_link
  peer_network = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/global/networks/vpc-network-development"
}


resource "google_compute_network_peering" "to-sql-db-network" {
  name = "to-sql-db-network-${var.environment}"
  peer_network = google_compute_network.sql-db-network.self_link
  network = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/global/networks/vpc-network-development"
}


resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private-vpc-connection" {
  network = google_compute_network.sql-db-network.id
  service = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.sql-db-private-ip-addr.name]
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "service-network-connection" {
  network = google_compute_network.sql-db-network.name
  service = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.sql-db-private-ip-addr.name]
}
```

Any insight that can be given to help me understand why they have different project ids, and how to get them to not have that, or if that is okay how to get the routes imported correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,